# Split a date range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling with a solution for a problem but I couldn't find anything similar here.

I have a table "A" like:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+
| user_id |    from    |     to     | attribute |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 | abc       |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

and I get a table "B" like:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+
| user_id |    from    |     to     | attribute |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-15 | def       |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

And what I need is:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+
| user_id |    from    |     to     | attribute |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-29 | abc       |
|       1 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-15 | def       |
|       1 | 2020-04-16 | 2020-12-31 | abc       |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

I tried just using insert and update but I couldn't figure out how to simultaneously do both. Is there a much simpler way? I read about CTE, could this be an approach?

I'd be very thankful for your help!

Edit: more examples

TABLE A

```
| user_id |    from    |     to     | attribute |
+=========+============+============+===========+
|       1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 | atr1      |
|       1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | atr2      |
|       2 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-06-15 | atr1      |
|       3 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-06-15 | atr3      |
```

TABLE B

```
| user_id |    from    |     to     | attribute |
+=========+============+============+===========+
|       1 | 2020-09-01 | 2021-02-15 | atr3      |
|       2 | 2020-04-15 | 2020-05-31 | atr2      |
|       3 | 2021-04-01 | 2022-01-01 | atr1      |
```

OUTPUT:

```
| user_id |    from    |     to     | attribute |
+=========+============+============+===========+
|       1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-08-31 | atr1      |
|       1 | 2020-09-01 | 2021-02-15 | atr3      |
|       1 | 2021-02-16 | 2021-12-31 | atr2      |
|       2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-04-14 | atr1      |
|       2 | 2020-04-15 | 2020-05-31 | atr2      |
|       2 | 2020-06-01 | 2021-06-15 | atr1      |
|       3 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | atr3      |
|       3 | 2021-04-01 | 2022-01-01 | atr1      |
```

Initially I just asked to split the date range and make a new row because the new attribute of table B is between the one in table A. But it's only a part of the problem. Maybe it's more clear with the new dataset(?)

Comment: I think you need more examples and a clearer explanation of what to do.  Why are these rows in different tables?  How deeply can the periods be nested?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Table B is data from another system. I get the attributes and a date range where there are going to be used. I can get multiple date ranges for each user id, they won't overlap in B but they can in table A. Could I answer your questions?

Comment: @Larnu I edited my question and added more samples. Thank you for your time! Is it understandable now?
I just need a solution to add a new row with the data range of table B while changing the end date of table A (start date minus one day) and simultaneously add a new row to table A with the end date of table B plus one day as the start day and the initial end day of table A as the end date

Comment: @tunaturner, I think your output is wrong in few places.Will you revise it and care to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Sample data,

```
create table #TableA( userid int, fromdt date  
,todt date, attribute varchar(10))

insert into #TableA (userid , fromdt  , todt , attribute)
values
( 1 ,'2020-01-01','2020-12-31' , 'atr1' ),
( 1 ,'2021-01-01','2021-12-31' , 'atr2' ),
( 2 ,'2020-01-01','2021-06-15' , 'atr1' ),
( 3 ,'2020-01-01','2021-06-15' , 'atr3' )

create table #TableB( userid int,fromdt date 
,todt date, attribute varchar(10))

insert into #TableB (userid,fromdt, todt, attribute)
values
( 1 ,'2020-09-01','2021-02-15' , 'atr3' ),
( 2 ,'2020-04-15','2020-05-31' , 'atr2' ),
( 3 ,'2021-04-01','2022-01-01' , 'atr1' )
;
```

The Script,

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM #TableA

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM #TableB
    )
    ,CTE2
AS (
    SELECT userid
        ,min(fromdt) minfromdt
        ,max(todt) maxtodt
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY userid
    )
    ,CTE3
AS (
    SELECT c.userid
        ,c.fromdt
        ,c.todt
        ,c.attribute
        ,LEAD(c.fromdt, 1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY c.userid ORDER BY c.fromdt
            ) LeadFromdt
    FROM CTE c
    )
    ,CTE4
AS (
    SELECT c3.userid
        ,c3.fromdt
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c3.todt > c3.LeadFromdt
                THEN dateadd(day, - 1, c3.leadfromdt)
                    --when c3.todt<c3.LeadFromdt then dateadd(day,-1,c3.leadfromdt)
            ELSE c3.todt
            END AS Todt
        ,
        --c3.todt as todt1,
        c3.attribute
    FROM CTE3 c3
    )
    ,CTE5
AS (
    SELECT userid
        ,fromdt
        ,todt
        ,attribute
    FROM CTE4

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c2.userid
        ,dateadd(day, 1, c4.Todt) AS Fromdt
        ,maxtodt AS Todt
        ,c4.attribute
    FROM CTE2 c2
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 c4.todt
            ,c4.attribute
        FROM cte4 c4
        WHERE c2.userid = c4.userid
        ORDER BY c4.Todt DESC
        ) c4
    WHERE c2.maxtodt > c4.Todt
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE5
ORDER BY userid
    ,fromdt

drop table #TableA, #TableB
```

Your output is wrong.

Also append other sample data in same example
 where my script is not working.

Comment: Thank you very much! This one helped me alot! I checked my samples and yes, there was a mistake. But there is also one in the second row of the output of your script. The 'to'-date must be '2021-02-15' but it is '2020-12-31'

Comment: @tunaturner, If second row must be '2021-02-15'  for userid 1 in my output then I must understand the logic behind it.what is the difference between 1st row and 2nd row for userid 1.Then only it can be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to work with a calendar table.  You can create one and reuse it later.
When you have one (here I called it "AllDates"), you can do something like this:

```
WITH cte
as
(
    select ad.theDate,u.userid,isnull(b.attrib,a.attrib) as attrib,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY u.userid, isnull(b.attrib,a.attrib)ORDER BY ad.theDate)
        - ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY u.userid ORDER BY ad.theDate) as grp
    from AllDates ad
    cross join (select userid from tableA union select userid from tableB) u
    left join tableB b on ad.theDate between b.frm and b.toD and u.userid = b.userid
    left join tableA a on ad.theDate between a.frm and a.toD and u.userid = a.userid
    where b.frm is not null 
    or a.frm is not null
)
SELECT userid,attrib,min(theDate) as frmD, max(theDate) as toD
FROM cte
GROUP BY userid,attrib,grp
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it and it works, but for more users it seems to take very long

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the request correctly the data from table A should be merged into table B to fill the gaps based on four scenarios, here is how I achieved it:

```
/*
    Scenario 1 - Use dates from B as base to be filled in from A
    - Start and end dates from B
*/
SELECT
    B.UserId,
    B.StartDate,
    B.EndDate,
    B.Attr
FROM #tmpB AS B

UNION
/*
    Scenario 2 - Start date between start and end date of another record
    - End date from B plus one day as start date
    - End date from A as end date
*/
SELECT
    B.UserId,
    DATEADD(DD, 1, B.EndDate) AS StartDate,
    A.EndDate,
    A.Attr
FROM #tmpB AS B
    JOIN #tmpA AS A ON
        B.UserId = A.UserId
        AND B.StartDate < A.StartDate
        AND B.EndDate > A.StartDate

UNION
/*
    Scenario 3 - End date between start and end date of another record or both dates between start and end date of another record
    - Start date from A as start date
    - Start date from B minus one as end date
*/
SELECT
    B.UserId,
    A.StartDate,
    DATEADD(DD, -1, B.StartDate) AS EndDate,
    A.Attr
FROM #tmpB AS B
    JOIN #tmpA AS A ON
        B.UserId = A.UserId
        AND (B.StartDate < A.EndDate AND B.EndDate > A.EndDate
        OR B.StartDate BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate AND B.EndDate BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate)

UNION
/*
    Scenario 4 - Both dates between start and end date of another record
    - End date from B minus one as start date
    - End date from A as end date
*/
SELECT
    B.UserId,
    DATEADD(DD, -1, B.EndDate) AS StartDate,
    A.EndDate,
    A.Attr
FROM #tmpB AS B
    JOIN #tmpA AS A ON
        B.UserId = A.UserId
        AND B.StartDate BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate
        AND B.EndDate BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate
```